# How to setup MX records on a shared application serving multiple domains?

Tags: dns, email, multiple-domains, mx

We are in the process of transitioning from 150 separate websites on individual domains to 150 domains all served by a central MVC app.

I am now wondering how to handle the MX record(s) on this new setup.  I want the easiest way of setting the MX record to a third party mailserver for all 150 domains.

I'm pretty new to DNS so please go easy if I've got something wrong.

---

**Domain / DNS Setup**

The main app resides in a fake / unregistered, plesk-only domain.

The 150 live websites are registered active domains. In Plesk I have created them as aliases to the fake domain. The DNS of the aliases is set to by 'synced' with the fake domain.

**Email Setup**

Email is managed by a third party server.

I have tried adding an MX record `mail.thirdpartyserver.com` on the fake domain, hoping the aliases would sync to this.  But it doesn't seem to be working.

Is this because the domain from which the DNS is synced is fake?

---

**Bonus question, possibly related...**

There is an option for each alias labeled "Mail Service" (shot below).  I don't know whether this should be off or on. I would "just try it", but because of the delay in DNS propogation, I'm finding it hard to assess the results of changes I make.

[image]

Comment: Yes. If you create a domain name that does not live in the wild, you cannot reference it externally (on the Internet). So for your 3rd party e-mail to work, it has to be a domain name that is registered. A supplier sub-domain should be just fine (like you have in your example).

Comment: Thank you :)  The aliases are real and active domains, but the domain they sync their DNS from is not.  Do you know how the 'syncing' of alias' DNS works in Plesk? Does it create new records that duplicate the master domain, or just pointers to the master's records?

Comment: I have no idea about Plesk. Sorry. I am rather old-school 'cuz I am old!! Admittedly, I was not sure that I understood that part of your question. I have done all kinds of crazy things with DNS, but I am not sure what is going on in your case. I am a "show me" guy. I probably would understand better if you and I were at your desk.

Comment: I up-voted your question to help get you some attention.

Comment: Thanks for that too. I'll accept help from any age, even those snarky little upstarts!  I tried to make it as clear as I could, but I did struggle a bit. I'll update it and see if that helps.

Comment: Okay. I get what synced means. That should be okay. You want to make sure that you have an A record in your DNS for all of the domain names. It is not clear if this is what you are doing, but that should work as long as all domain names exist on the server. As well, your bonus question, you probably do not want to check being a *master*. This means that you are allowing other DNS servers to pull from your local DNS. I am assuming that you are using a registrars DNS or a DNS service to host your domain names. Being a master is usually reserved for creating a DNS topology.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you are unable to alias the MX records in that manner. While all the domains can target A records to the same server to use the exact same code for all the domains each domains MX record would have to individually be pointed to the mail server and the mail server would have to be configured to work with each domain and define the mailboxes for each domain. You can on the mail server configure forward mailboxes so that any email sent to the address will be automatically forwarded to an alternate email address but you can't simply alias all MX records automatically without defining MX records in each of you 150 domains.