# How CDN Relates to DNS Resolution and Content Fetching

Tags: dns, cdn

I was trying to do a deeper dive on CDN and DNS

1. I understood the concepts around ISP, resolver cache, Root nameserver, TLD Nameserver, Authoritative Nameserver etc. i.e. a website (e.g. [www.google.com](http://www.google.com)) is rendered on browser.
2. I understood that CDN is a network of servers which caches, distributes, and protects static and dynamic contents fast and effectively, and at cost+performance. Some CDNs could be hosted within an ISP's DC to make this experience even better, but they are usually set up as Edge Locations (with more sophisticated routing and switch equipment)

What I didn't manage to pinpoint or connect the dots for - when DNS resolution happens and I get the IP address of my content, am I looking at the CDN's IP address or something else?

HOw does CDN-managed content play part as part of post-DNS resolution i.e when the contents are fetched?

Comment: Related answer [How to setup email if using a third party hosting and the site is hosted on Netlify?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/133596)

Comment: CDN is just when I pay Cloudflare so I can serve my site from their server. Except Cloudflare's server  doesn't have all my webpages so it downloads them from my server as needed.